# How to move all operators after all numbers in Java?

Tags: java

How do I move all operators to after all numbers given inside infix.txt which is

```
"1.5 - 3.16 * 2.333 / 0.25 + 4.1"
```

Output should be:

```
0.25 1.5 2.333 3.16 4.1 + - * /
```

Here's the code

```
public class SplitString{
   static boolean isOperator(char ch){
     return ch=='+' || ch=='-' || ch=='/' || ch=='*';
   }

   static boolean precedence(char a,char b){
     switch(a){
         case '+': return !(b=='-') || !(b=='*') || (b=='+') || !(b=='/');
        default : return false;
     }
   }

  static public void main(String... args){
       String filename="infix.txt";
       StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
       try{
             java.util.Scanner sc=new java.util.Scanner(new java.io.File(filename));
             while(sc.hasNextLine()){
                   String s=sc.nextLine();
                   System.out.println(s);
                   java.util.Stack stack=new java.util.Stack();
                   String[] st=s.split("\\s");
                   for(String ss:st){
                         char ch=ss.charAt(0);
                         if(isOperator(ch)){
                               switch(ch){
                                     case '+': if (!stack.empty() || stack.peek().toString().charAt(0)=='+')
                                           stack.pop();
                                           else stack.push(ch);
                                           break;
                                     case '-': if (!stack.empty() || stack.peek().toString().charAt(0)=='-')
                                           stack.pop();
                                           else stack.push(ch);
                                           break;
                                     case '*': if (!stack.empty() || stack.peek().toString().charAt(0)=='*')
                                           stack.pop();
                                           else stack.push(ch);
                                           break;
                                     case '/': if (!stack.empty() || stack.peek().toString().charAt(0)=='/')
                                           stack.pop();
                                           else stack.push(ch);
                                           break;        
                               }
                         }else sb.append(ss);
                   }
                     for(;!stack.empty();sb.append(stack.pop()));
                     System.out.println(sb.toString());
             }
       }catch(Exception e){ e.getMessage();}                    
  }
}
```

Comment: what about negative numbers do you want to move the minus also?

Comment: @YCF_L from what my professor said just disregard the negative number as of now so we won't get confuse.

Comment: ok what is the problem with your code?

Comment: @YCF_L as of now it only display what's in the infix.txt. It won't move all operators to the left side.

Comment: @YCF_L A regex won't respect operator precedence. `1 + 2 * 3` should become `1 2 3 * +`. Notice the operators have switched places.

Comment: @YCF_L but our professor said that we shouldn't edit the code, just add some to it.

Comment: @JohnKugelman are you sure? check this [demo please](https://ideone.com/aou8Xj)

Comment: @YCF_L Yes, as I said, it should be `1 2 3 * +` and your demo prints `1 2 3 + *`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman sorry I don't get you, why It should be `1 2 3 * +` and not `1 2 3 + *`!

Comment: `*` has higher precedence than `+`. See [Reverse Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) on Wikipedia.

Comment: oops I don't know about that @JohnKugelman thank you for the information I appreciate it

Comment: I'm new to Java and our professor said just use the code above and just add something to it, though I added some code but it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the kiss of death is in this line:

```
 }catch(Exception e){ e.getMessage();}
```

Here you don't print the exception if you get one. This is rarely a good idea. When I ran this it gave me a [`EmptyStackException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EmptyStackException.html). This is because you have `if(!stack.empty() || stack.peek().toString().charAt(0)==`... When you have the `||` both sides are evaluated. So on the first run the `Stack` will be empty and the call `stack.peek()` will throw an exception. I believe you wanted to change all of the `||` to `&&`. This will make it so that if the `Stack` is empty the right side won't be evaluated. When you change this it will yield: (With the test case `8 * 9 + 9`)

```
899+*
```

Next we need to figure out how to use the `precedence()` method. I wrote an `order()` method that simply iterates the `Stack` and check which has a higher precedence and reorder the `Stack` accordingly. With these changes we get:

```
899*+
```

A couple notes:

- If the text file contains empty lines this will cause errors
- It is good practice to parametrize your `Stack` (Change `java.util.Stack stack=new java.util.Stack();` to `java.util.Stack<Character> stack=new java.util.Stack<Character>();`)
- As mentioned at the top it is almost never a good idea to eat an exception. Change `catch(Exception e){ e.getMessage();}` to `catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace();}`

Here is the code with the changes:

```
static boolean isOperator(char ch){
     return ch=='+' || ch=='-' || ch=='/' || ch=='*';
   }

   static boolean precedence(Character a,Character b){
     switch(a){
         case '+': return !(b=='-') || !(b=='*') || (b=='+') || !(b=='/');
        default : return false;
     }
   }

  static public void main(String... args){
       String filename="king.txt";
       StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
       try{
             java.util.Scanner sc=new java.util.Scanner(new java.io.File(filename));
             while(sc.hasNextLine()){
                   String s=sc.nextLine();
                   System.out.println(s);
                   java.util.Stack<Character> stack=new java.util.Stack<Character>();
                   String[] st=s.split("\\s");
                   for(String ss:st){
                         char ch=ss.charAt(0);
                         if(isOperator(ch)){
                               switch(ch){
                                     case '+': if (!stack.empty() && stack.peek().toString().charAt(0)=='+')
                                           stack.pop();
                                           else stack.push(ch);
                                           break;
                                     case '-': if (!stack.empty() && stack.peek().toString().charAt(0)=='-')
                                           stack.pop();
                                           else stack.push(ch);
                                           break;
                                     case '*': if (!stack.empty() && stack.peek().toString().charAt(0)=='*')
                                           stack.pop();
                                           else stack.push(ch);
                                           break;
                                     case '/': if (!stack.empty() && stack.peek().toString().charAt(0)=='/')
                                           stack.pop();
                                           else stack.push(ch);
                                           break;        
                               }
                         }else sb.append(ss);
                   }
                   order(stack);
                     for(;!stack.empty();sb.append(stack.pop()));
                        System.out.println(sb.toString());


             }
       }catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace();}        

  }
  static Stack<Character> order(Stack<Character> stack) {
      for(int i = 0; i < stack.size()-1; i++) {
          if(!precedence(stack.elementAt(i), stack.elementAt(i+1))) {
              Character temp = stack.pop();
              Character temp2 = stack.pop();
              stack.push(temp);
              stack.push(temp2);

          }
      }
      return stack;
  }
```

Comment: What library should i include, it gave error. Stack<Character> error: cannot find symbol

Comment: Did you `import java.util.Stack;`?

Comment: Wow it worked, what you said was correct change || to &&. Thank you so much sir

Comment: How do I add space or like split them using space or comma?

Comment: @MicFlurry Where you append you can simply add `+ " "`

Comment: Oh right thank you sir, I have a question though your method on ordering the operator is from right to left right? how do I order them through MDAS?

Comment: @MicFlurry You'd have to change the `precedence()` method to be ordered MDAS

Comment: are you busy sir? would mind helping me also with my infix to postfix calculator? I'm kinda stuck right now don't know what to do.

Comment: @MicFlurry Go ahead and ask a new question and I'll try to help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51317341/how-to-create-a-infix-to-postfix-calcultor-in-java here's the link sir, I've updated the code but I want to make it more less complicated and easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach without using Stacks, just with arrays and sorting algorithms.

1. Split out the numbers
2. Split out the operators
3. Sort the numbers
4. Sort the operators
5. Combine sorted numbers with sorted operators

### Code

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String data = "1.5 - 3.16 * 2.333 / 0.25 + 4.1";
        // Remove any spaces
        data = data.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        System.out.println(data);

        // Get the numbers
        String[] numbers = data.split("[+*/-]");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));

        // Get the operators
        String[] operators = data.replaceAll("\\d*[.]?\\d*", " ").trim().split("  "); // Operators are separated by 2 spaces
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(operators));

        // Sort the numbers (Simple bubble sort)
        String temp = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            double num1 = Double.valueOf(numbers[i]);
            for (int j = 1; j < (numbers.length - i); j++) {
                double num2 = Double.valueOf(numbers[j]);
                if (num1 > num2) {
                    temp = numbers[i];
                    numbers[i] = numbers[j];
                    numbers[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));

        // Sort operators (+, -, *, /)
        int index = 0;
        index = moveOperator(operators, "+", index);
        index = moveOperator(operators, "-", index);
        index = moveOperator(operators, "*", index);
        index = moveOperator(operators, "/", index);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(operators));

        // Combine arrays
        String[] answer = Arrays.copyOf(numbers, numbers.length + operators.length);
        System.arraycopy(operators, 0, answer, numbers.length, operators.length);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(answer));
    }

    private static int moveOperator(String[] operators, String operator, int index) {
        String temp = "";
        for (int i = index + 1; i < operators.length; i++) {
            if (operators[i].contentEquals(operator)) {
                temp = operators[index];
                operators[index] = operators[i];
                operators[i] = temp;

                index++;
            }
        }

        return index;
    }
}
```

### Result

```
1.5-3.16*2.333/0.25+4.1
[1.5, 3.16, 2.333, 0.25, 4.1]
[-, *, /, +]
[0.25, 3.16, 1.5, 2.333, 4.1]
[+, -, *, /]
[0.25, 3.16, 1.5, 2.333, 4.1, +, -, *, /]
```

Comment: It worked great, but if I use this my effort on adding some code / conditions would be pointless. But I really appreciated the help I tried studying your code on how to split the the numbers and operators by space and comma, still confused lol.

Comment: The splitting is done with using a regex pattern.  The Arrays.toString() is what adds the commas to the output.

Comment: How should I do it with my code? Right now works fine but the output don't have spaces.